# Only convert codecs(preserve audio and subtitles)

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, video-conversion, codec

I have a video file h265 mkv which has dual audio and multiple subtitles.
I want to convert it to h264 since it doesn't require further transcoding on my jellyfin server.
But I haven't been able to find the correct arguments to preserve all the audio and subtitles and only transcode the video.

The command i came up with so far:

```
./ffmpeg -y -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i "input.mkv" -c:a copy -c:v h264_nvenc -ss 00:00:13 -t 30 -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a:1 -map 0:s:0 -map 0:s:1 "output.mp4"
```

I get the output with it

```
Automatic encoder selection failed for output stream #0:3. Default encoder for format mp4 (codec none) is probably disabled. Please choose an encoder manually.
Error selecting an encoder for stream 0:3
```

I get that output when doing both transcoding and muxing at the same time

Individually transcoding to mp4 and muxing is fine

Thanks

Comment: As said in error message, choose a valid encoder.

Comment: Apart from the answer by Rotem, `-map 0` is enough to keep all the streams (video, audio, subtitles) that are present in the input file, you don't need to map them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

We may select subtitles codec by adding `-c:s mov_text` argument, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31210930/4926757):

`ffmpeg -y -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i "input.mkv" -c:a copy -c:v h264_nvenc -c:s mov_text -ss 00:00:13 -t 30 -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a:1 -map 0:s:0 -map 0:s:1 "output.mp4"`

Another option is selecting MKV container instead of MP4 container:

`ffmpeg -y -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i "input.mkv" -c:a copy -c:v h264_nvenc -ss 00:00:13 -t 30 -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a:1 -map 0:s:0 -map 0:s:1 "output.mkv"`

---

You are experiencing the issue "*FFmpeg doesn't auto-select subtitle codec for MP4*" that described in the following [ticket](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/2260).
"stream #0:3" is a subtitle stream, and we have to specify the subtitle codec **explicitly**.

---

For testing, we may reproduce the issue using synthetic pattern with subtitles:

- Start by creating two subtitles text files:

`in0.srt`:

```
1
00:00:00,0 --> 00:00:01,0
Eng 0 to 1

2
00:00:01,0 --> 00:00:02,0
Eng 1 to 2

3
00:00:02,0 --> 00:00:03,0
Eng 2 to 3

4
00:00:03,0 --> 00:00:04,0
Eng 3 to 4
```

`in1.srt`:

```
1
00:00:00,0 --> 00:00:01,0
Ita 0 to 1

2
00:00:01,0 --> 00:00:02,0
Ita 1 to 2

3
00:00:02,0 --> 00:00:03,0
Ita 2 to 3

4
00:00:03,0 --> 00:00:04,0
Ita 3 to 4
```

- Create `input.mkv` with synthetic video, two synthetic audio streams, and two subtitles streams using FFmpeg (for testing):

`ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=384x206:rate=1 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=400 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=1000 -sub_charenc CP1252 -i in0.srt -sub_charenc CP1252 -i in1.srt -map:v 0 -map:a 1 -map:a 2 -map:s 3 -map:s 4 -vcodec libx265 -crf 17 -pix_fmt yuv420p -acodec aac -ar 22050 -scodec ass -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -metadata:s:s:1 language=ita -disposition:s:s:1 default+forced -t 10 input.mkv`

- Execute the FFmpeg command from the question for reproducing the error message:

`ffmpeg -y -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i "input.mkv" -c:a copy -c:v h264_nvenc -ss 00:00:13 -t 30 -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a:1 -map 0:s:0 -map 0:s:1 "output.mp4"`

Error message:

> Automatic encoder selection failed for output stream #0:3. Default encoder for format mp4 (codec none) is probably disabled. Please choose an encoder manually.
> Error selecting an encoder for stream 0:3

- Executing the "corrected" FFmpeg command (without `-ss` and `-t`):

`ffmpeg -y -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i "input.mkv" -c:a copy -c:v h264_nvenc -c:s mov_text -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a:1 -map 0:s:0 -map 0:s:1 "output.mp4"`

- Examining `output.mp4` using [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) tool.

MediaInfo output:

```
General
Complete name                            : C:\Tmp\output.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size                                : 214 KiB
Duration                                 : 10 s 78 ms
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 174 kb/s
Writing application                      : Lavf59.27.100

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L2.1
Format settings                          : CABAC / 2 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 2 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 10 s 0 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 31.1 kb/s
Maximum bit rate                         : 3 200 kb/s
Width                                    : 384 pixels
Height                                   : 206 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 1.85:1
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 1.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.393
Stream size                              : 37.9 KiB (18%)
Codec configuration box                  : avcC

Audio #1
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
Duration                                 : 10 s 78 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 67.5 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Channel layout                           : C
Sampling rate                            : 22.05 kHz
Frame rate                               : 21.533 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 83.0 KiB (39%)
Default                                  : Yes
Alternate group                          : 1

Audio #2
ID                                       : 3
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
Duration                                 : 10 s 78 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 66.2 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Channel layout                           : C
Sampling rate                            : 22.05 kHz
Frame rate                               : 21.533 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 82.6 KiB (39%)
Default                                  : No
Alternate group                          : 1

Text #1
ID                                       : 4
Format                                   : Timed Text
Muxing mode                              : sbtl
Codec ID                                 : tx3g
Duration                                 : 10 s 46 ms
Duration_FirstFrame                      : -954 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 100 b/s
Stream size                              : 125 Bytes (0%)
Language                                 : English
Default                                  : No
Forced                                   : No
Alternate group                          : 3

Text #2
ID                                       : 5
Format                                   : Timed Text
Muxing mode                              : sbtl
Codec ID                                 : tx3g
Duration                                 : 10 s 46 ms
Duration_FirstFrame                      : -954 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 100 b/s
Stream size                              : 125 Bytes (0%)
Language                                 : Italian
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No
Alternate group                          : 3
```

In case it's still not working because my assumptions are wrong, you may use MediaInfo for examining your input file (add the information to your question).